# Mvc Helper Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper

I'm writing some custom helpers the current one involves a sort of "datagrid control" type helper and i seem to have hit a bit of a hurdle.

if i was in a razor view i coud something like Html.EditorFor(someExpression) and i can't seem to find a way to do that within the context of my helper code within my custom helper.

Effectively i'm trying to call a helper from within a helper.

Here's an example in the most basic form i can think of:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Test(dynamic Model)
{
   return new MvcHtmlString( Html.textBox(Model.SomeProperty) )
}
```

Any ideas ?

I figured out how dumb this was when I added a using statement like this to my code ...

```
using Html = System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Talk about simple ... note to self ... pay attention to framework !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your helper method into a extension method instead.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Test(this HtmlHelper html, dynamic Model)
{
   return new MvcHtmlString( html.textBox(Model.SomeProperty) )
}
```

You call this by first have a using of the namespace where (the class where) the method is and then just `Html.Test(Model)`